# android get intent in a running activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities A and B and the activity A starts B and keeps running.
I want to send back some info from B to A which is still running in background.

I'm doing this but B is starting a new A activity instead of using the previous one.

B

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(context, ObtenerDatos.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", StationID);
context.startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

And A gets the data as this:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      if (extras != null) {
           String datas= extras.getString("EXTRA_ID");
           if (datas!= null) {
                // do stuff
           }
      }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Android works as designed -- you are explicitly starting an activity, after all. If this is a return result, use `setActivityResult` in B and `onActivityResult` in A. Since A is not visible, there's really no reason to send it data until B closes -- if you feel you have a need to do so, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` for this (see [Starting Activities and Getting Results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)).

For example, in Activity A:

```
private static final int B_REQUEST = 0;

// ...

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent bIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivityForResult(bIntent, B_REQUEST);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == B_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // Get data out of the data Intent
    }
}
```

In ActivityB when you want to return to Activity A:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
// use intent.putExtra() to store your result data
setResult(Activity.Result_OK, data);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. If an activity is already running it will  be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in instead of creating a new one.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setClass(context, ObtenerDatos.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", StationID);
context.startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) from A to start B?

When B is done, just set the result and call `finish()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(DATA_EXTRA, data);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

finish();
```

Then, in A you use [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", StationID);
context.startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

I think that the problem is the finish(); becouse how can Acvtivity B still run if you finish it?